# 'supportingText' overflowing parent in Jetpack Compose Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have an `EditText` in my Composable function that have a `supportingText` defined as follow:

```
supportingText = ui.emailError?.let {
   {
      Text(
         text = it,
         color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
      )
   }
},
```

The results though are not what I expect it to be:
[image]

Layout Inspector:
[image]

The `Text` composable has a padding at the `start`, and overflows its parent, any idea why?

I'm using:
`compose-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3", version.ref = "compose-material3" }`
with `1.1.2` as `compose-material3` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are observing is a bug that was [reported in the Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270523016).

The issue was marked as fixed and should be resolved by using Material3 library version `1.2.0-alpha02` or above.

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to find anything by googling.